# Adding a method to a child class named same as an inherited method

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading

I have method `f()` in class `A` and child class `B` where I add method `f(int)`. So I have both `f()` and `f(int)` in `B` if I understand right. I want to use `f()` in another method of `B` but it's an error.

```
class A {
public:
    int f() {
        return 3;
    }
};

class B : public A {
    int x;
public:
    int f(int a) {
        return a * 2;
    }
    void g() {
        x = f();
       // no matching function for call to 'B::f()'
       // candidate is 'int B::f(int)'
    }
};
```

If I remove `f(int)` from `B` it will work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So I have both `f()` and `f(int)` in `B` if I understand right.

No, `A::f()` is hidden at the scope of `B`. Because the member function named `f` could be found at the scope of class `B`, and then name lookup will stop, the base class version `f` won't be found and considered for overload resolution. At last compile failed because the function parameter doesn't match. It is a kind of name hiding.

You can introduce `A::f` via `using`.

```
class B : public A {
    int x;
public:
    using A::f;
    int f(int a) {
        return a * 2;
    }
    void g() {
        x = f();
    }
};
```

> If I remove `f(int)` from `B` it will work.

Then the name lookup failed at the scope of class `B`, the further scopes will be examined and `A::f` will be found at the scope of base class `A`, then it works well.

See [Unqualified name lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup)

Answer (score 1):

You can use scope resolution operator `::`

Replace `x = f();` with `x = A::f();`

```
class A {
public:
    int f() {
        return 3;
    }
};

class B : public A {
    int x;
public:
    int f(int a) {
        return a * 2;
    }
    void g() {
        x = A::f();
    }
};
```